# Selecting all button also selects checkboxes in different columns in Element UI

Tags: vue.js, types, html-table, selection, element-ui

I have el-table and I need three columns with type="selectable". 
When I do that and click select all button, all checkboxes are selected. Here is a video:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBSdc.jpg

Here is my code:

```
<el-table :data="result">
  <el-table-column type="selection" prop="ClipID" label="Image Preview"></el-table-column>
  <el-table-column type="selection" prop="ClipID" label="Clip Preview"></el-table-column>
  <el-table-column type="selection" prop="ProducerID" label="Member Files"></el-table-column>
  </el-table>
```

Comment: There's a typo, it should be `<el-table>` in first line. Can you share your `script` code as well? will give a better look to understand or maybe a codepen.

Comment: I don't think `type="selection"` does what you think it does. As for why all rows are selected, we'd need to see more code.

Comment: Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/emu01y4z/2/

When I click a checkbox, I want it to react only that column it belongs, not to all, like it does now. Also, I want to display label names(Image Preview, Clip Preview, Member Files)